# Custom .traineddata file usage in the tesseract in R

Tags: r, tesseract

I have a bunch of .JPGs with some text at the bottom, which consists mostly (but not exclusively of numbers). I wish to use the *tesseract* package in R to be able to 'read' the text in those .JPGs. Unfortunately, the base tesseract language proved too inaccurate to be worth using. Subsequently I tried using the *Magick* package to adjust the pictures (crop, resize convert etc) hoping to get a better reading from tesseract, but in my case this failed to get satisfactory results.

I eventually managed to use the description on this link (https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-ocr-with-tesseract-a4341e4564b6) to create a new custom language in Tesseract 4.1.1 (as downloaded from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), which I named **font_name.traineddata**. The custom-made **font_name.traineddata** works perfectly on the Tesseract 4.1.1 console and shows significant improvement in results on the base language.

The question I have is: How I get the **font_name.traineddata** file to be part of the *ocr* command in R? I have tried the simple solution of just pasting the **font_name.traineddata** file into the appropriate tessdata folder in the package *tesseract* (the same folder that also contains the standard english data file called **eng.traineddata**) and then trying the following:

```
font_name <- tesseract ("font_name")
ocr("C:/1.jpg", engine = font_name)
```

This does not work and gives the error :

```
Error in tesseract_engine_internal(datapath, language, configs, opt_names,  : 
  Unable to find training data for: font_name. Please consult manual for: ?tesseract_download
```

tesseract_download seems to be of no use, as it is a helper function to download training data from the official tessdata repository. I have also tried renaming the file to a three character name, with the same error.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to make custom .traineddata files work with *ocr* in R?

Comment: Can you make sure that `font_named.traineddata` is present in the path you get from `tesseract_info()$datapath`? It could just be that it is pointing to the wrong path. Your file name seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks so much slamballais. That worked. Hartelijk bedankt.